# Kotlin +spring boot post request default boolean value

Tags: rest, spring-boot, kotlin, boolean

Currently I am working on spring boot restful web app with Kotlin.
I want to add a boolean flag to the body of a post request and its default value is true if is not passed in

DTO:

```
data class PersonDTO(

    @field:NotNull
    val name: String,

    val enabledProfile: Boolean = true // setting this to true is not working
)
```

How can I set the flag `enabledProfile` to true by default?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. I tried it on my own, and it works fine.

Comment: You should just add a default value for the field `name` too, since it can't be null. I think it's a good practice.

Comment: I dont want a default value for `name` field, if no value passed then the response should be a bad request status code

Comment: As you wish. Did you eventually fixed your problem?

Comment: currently I declared `enabledProfile` as optional then check its value in the mapper ad set it to true if it is == null